# How to automate data entry into a website

Tags: automation

I'm asked to input 15 to 25 sets of data into a website once daily.  It requires logging into the website, clicking a button, then selecting 2-7 checkboxes, clicking button, selecting up to 3 more checkboxes, then inputting numerical values for each of those checkboxes, then clicking a 'save/next' button.   This process needs to be repeated 15 to 25 times.  Because much of the data is repetitive and the data sets rarely change, I want a method to automate 10 sets with certain chexkboxes and numbers, then 5 sets with other checkboxes and numbers. I have no programming experience but i'm willing to learn. Another possible barrier is the computers are admin locked which has prevented me from downloading a program to repeat mouse movements.

Answer (score 2):

The options depend on the web site. If the web site is sending the data to an API, it may be possible to register with the API provider and provide the same data without the web interface. This situation is ideal, as it is more stable than anything else.

If the data is a form being posted without authentication, it should be possible to submit the data programmatically to the same endpoint. Raw HTML forms can be spoofed pretty easily with simple HTTP commands (`curl` would work for a raw form).

Of course, raw forms and APIs may not be available, in which case you are stuck doing some kind of screenscraping and automation. Using Selenium to remote control a web browser would be the baseline, with plenty of other tools to scrape and automate browsers existing.

So, in conclusion, the options in order of desirability are:

1. Use the API that backs the service (i.e. call a SOAP or REST API).
2. Submit the HTTP request programmatically (i.e. a script or `curl` command to submit the equivalent of the form data to the same endpoint).
3. Screenscraping / browser scripting (i.e. Selenium).

Comment: Was looking into 1 and 2 but it seemed a bit difficult to start.   Was watching tutorials on scriptilitious and the curl command.  I was about to start programming a script but decided to check out selenium.  Found the selenium IDE program which operates as a chrome app and it works beautifully for what I need.  Just need to create 3 or 4 more 'project' templates.  Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

As your role is apparently not that of a software developer, your options may be a bit constrained. The fact that your computer is locked down administratively somewhat indicates that the organization does not want you to use automation tools, doing it anyway might get you in trouble.

The proper way would be to write a process improvement proposal so that a faster and less error-prone solution can be installed officially. However, this requires that the organization is willing and able to improve its processes and to accept suggestions from employees outside the regular IT ranks. Many organizations don't have that flexibility.